# How to find the volume of $n$-ball numerically?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

If I have the coordinates of the points on the surface of the $n$-ball then, how can I find the volume? or how can I generalize trapezoidal rule for integration?

Comment: The [volume of an $n$-ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball) is given by $\frac{pi^\frac{n}{2}{\Gamma (\frac{n}{2}+1)}r^n$. Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do it would be using Monte Carlo integration. Surround the ball by a box of known volume and sample points inside the box, checking whether they're inside the ball.